# how can ggvis export and save plot in Rstudio

Tags: r, ggvis

I am just switching from Windows to Mac OS.
and I cannot save (or export) plot from ggvis in R studio.
Now I can still see these two windows:

[image: First window]

[image: second window]

but when I click save, nothing happened. and nothing saved in my directory.

Is there anyone knowing how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You display your plot in the preview window but it's more efficient to use designated [export](https://rdrr.io/cran/ggvis/man/export_png.html) functions:

```
export_png(vis, file = NULL)
export_svg(vis, file = NULL)
```

If you prefer to export by hand just use the export option available through the viewer:

[image: RStudio ggvis export]